# Why does -fPIC hinder inlining?

Tags: c++, g++, inline

I have this `foo.cpp`:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int add_wrapper(int a, int b) {
    return add(a,b);
}
```

Compiling like so

```
g++ -c -S -fPIC -O4 -finline-functions  foo.cpp -o foo.s
```

Gives the (demangled) assembly:

```
    .globl  add(int, int)
    .type   add(int, int), @function
add(int, int):
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    leal    (%rdi,%rsi), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   add(int, int), .-add(int, int)
    .p2align 4
    .globl  add_wrapper(int, int)
    .type   add_wrapper(int, int), @function
add_wrapper(int, int):
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    jmp add(int, int)@PLT
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   add_wrapper(int, int), .-add_wrapper(int, int)
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0"
```

Note that `add()` is not inlined.

However, without `-fPIC`, I get

```
    .globl  add(int, int)
    .type   add(int, int), @function
add(int, int):
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    leal    (%rdi,%rsi), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   add(int, int), .-add(int, int)
    .p2align 4
    .globl  add_wrapper(int, int)
    .type   add_wrapper(int, int), @function
add_wrapper(int, int):
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    leal    (%rdi,%rsi), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3:
    .size   add_wrapper(int, int), .-add_wrapper(int, int)
```

With `add()` inlined.

If I add `inline` to the declaration of `add()` and compile with `-fPIC`, I get

```
    .globl  add_wrapper(int, int)
    .type   add_wrapper(int, int), @function
add_wrapper(int, int):
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    leal    (%rdi,%rsi), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   add_wrapper(int, int), .-add_wrapper(int, int)
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0"
```

With `add()` omitted entirely.

So it seems that inlining is not disallowed by `-fPIC` because the compiler will inline if I label the function `inline`, but I don't understand why the compiler is unwilling to inline automatically with '-fPIC'.

Does anyone know why this is?

Is there a flag that will convince `g++` to inline with `-fPIC` but without labeling functions as `inline`?

I'm using g++ 11.2, but Compiler Explorer shows that the behavior is consistent across versions: https://godbolt.org/z/Y14edz968.

Comment: `-O4`? There's no such optimization level in neither llvm or GCC.

Comment: -fsemantic-interposition could also be relevant.

Comment: OP, JSYK, anything larger than 3 is treated as equivalent to `-O3`. See [How many GCC optimization levels are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778538/how-many-gcc-optimization-levels-are-there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the `always_inline` attribute to `add`, you can see the compiler error when it tries to inline:

```cpp
warning: 'always_inline' function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
    1 | [[gnu::always_inline]] int add(int a, int b) {
      |                            ^~~

In function 'int add_wrapper(int, int)':
error: inlining failed in call to 'always_inline' 'int add(int, int)': function body can be overwritten at link time
note: called from here
    6 |     return add(a,b);
      |            ~~~^~~~~
```

The `add(int, int)` symbol might end up being something else (e.g., another library that was in `LD_PRELOAD` with an `int add(int, int)` is loaded first, your `add_wrapper` should call that one).

You can fix this by making `add` invisible (`[[gnu::visibility("hidden")]]`) or not giving it external linkage (with an anonymous namespace or `static`).

Or you can make g++ assume this will never happen with the switch `-fno-semantic-interposition` (which is the default on clang).

See [New option in GCC 5.3: -fno-semantic-interposition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35745543) for more information about semantic interposition.

Answer (score 2):

Using `-fPIC` implies that you intend your functions to be used in a library. As neither function is labeled `static`, the compiler cannot assume anything and must make it available to link.

The function may still be used inline elsewhere in the compiled object code, but again, it cannot be removed from actual existence.

If you wish to remove a function from external availability, either label it with `static`

```
static int add( ... ) { ... }
```

or wrap it in an unnamed `namespace`.

```
namespace
{
  int add(...) { ... }
}
```

At this point it can be inlined (either implicitly or explicitly) because you have specifically marked it as unavailable to external code, and consequently it might be optimized out of actual existence.